# Derive a radius of convergence for complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

From $\tan(z)$ we know that the radius of convergence for series which represents $\tan(z)$ is not the less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I’m interested in derivation the radius of its series without finding the coefficients by Taylor formula. Is it possible to do so far? If yes - how?

Comment: What is the difference with your previous question?

Comment: So I found the radius of circle in which $tan(z)$ converge to its series. But the radius of convergence of the series itself may be bigger that for $tan(z)$

Comment: Since the tangent is not  defined at $\frac\pi 2$…

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, isn't it simply $R=\pi/2$? A corollary of proving that every function analytic on a domain $D$ has a power series expansion on that domain is that the series has radius of convergence equal to the distance to the nearest singularity. We have 
$$
\tan z=\dfrac{\sin z}{\cos z}
$$ 
which has a singularities at $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: z=n\pi/2;n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ with the first singularities being at $\pm\pi/2$. Thus 
$$
\tan z=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k
$$
has radius of convergence $R=\pi/2$. Of course you'll have to investigate convergence on the boundary.

Edit: I've made an error in my quoting. To be pedantic, the radius of convergence is the largest $R$ such that $f(z)$ extends to be analytic on $\{\lvert z\rvert<R\}$.

Also, after reading another answer I think I understand the question a bit more. You want to know if the power series can be extended and have a larger radius of convergence. Well, we have a singularity at $z_0=\pi/2$. Let's assume that $\tan z$ extends to be analytic at $z_0$. This would imply that $z_0$ is a removable singularity. However, by the Riemann removable singularity theorem, this implies that 
$$
\lim_{z\to\pi/2}\lvert\tan z\rvert=L
$$ 
for a finite $L$. This is a contradiction since $\tan z$ is unbounded as $z\rightarrow z_0$. Thus $\{\lvert z\rvert<\pi/2\}$ is the largest set that $\tan z$ extends to be analytic on, hence $R=\pi/2$ is the radius of convergence of our series.